# Usage of ないだけで in this situation

Tags: reading-comprehension, particle-だけ

[image]

Context: In the previous page, the other character is complaining people are misunderstanding/drawing fanart of her manga on twitter, so her colleague tell her this. Her answer after this is "no way I could do that."

My reading is that 訴えれば is "should we sue (them)" or maybe "bring the issue to their attention"?

To which then he add

> どの作家もやってないだけで全然勝てるんじゃない?

I understand "どの作家もやってない" is "it's not something any writer do", but I'm stumbled on the usage of だけで here. "Just by being something no author ever did, you can win it?"

Comment: Should be a dup [Does "～の違いだけで" mean "the only difference"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/95858)

Answer (score 3):

This 訴える means "to sue" in the legal sense. This だけ is "just" or "only". Compare:

- どの作家もやってない。
  No author has done it.
- どの作家もやってない**だけ**だ。
  It's **just** that no author has done it.
  Simply, no authors has done it.
  No authors has done it, nothing more.

So the translation is:

> じゃあ訴えれば?
> Then why not sue them?
>
> どの作家もやってないだけで、全然勝てるんじゃない?
> It's just that no author has done it yet; (if you do,) you can surely win, can't you?

Similar usage of だけ:

- [Help me understand 言ってみただけだよ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/41488/5010)
- [そんなもん見るな見るなっ。ほしくなっても空しいだけだぞ。](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32540/5010)
- [Translating the set phrase 後は～～だけ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/46537/5010)